# Can you set graphical layout preview-only text on a TextView?

Tags: android, graphical-layout-editor

I have a styled TextView whose real text is populated dynamically at runtime.  The Graphical Layout view is very useful for getting a feel on how this component works with others in terms of look and feel, etc.  There is no sensible default to this text field and I wish it to be blank before being populated.  If I don't specify any text in the TextView declaration then the TextView is blank.  I can set the text manually using:

```
<TextView
     ...
     android:text="Preview text"/>
```

and then switch to the Graphical Layout.  However, I must remember to remove this or risk it being shipped in my production version.

Is there a way to specify text which is only seen in the Graphical Layout preview but not applicable at runtime?

EDIT:  I'm using Eclipse ADT.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes you can with the design tools extension attributes in Android Studio.

See this page https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html

Basically you define the tools namespace

```
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Then use it to set your placeholder text.

```
<EditText 
        tools:text="John Doe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This actually works with most (if not all xml attributes).

e.g

```
tools:visibility="gone"
```

would set the preview visibility to "gone" but the runtime visibility would be unchanged.

Comment: Excellent, thanks @Kuffs.  Unfortunately, I'm still using ADT and haven't migrated to Android Studio yet, but will definitely look forward to this feature when I do.

Comment: Sorry not sure if the feature has made it over to ADT plugin yet.

Comment: Nope, I can confirm that using ``tools:text`` doesn't work with ADT.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is, the only possible way is when you declare your TextView, you say after, `tv.setText("");` this way you will always find it blank at runtime

Comment: As mentioned by @Kuffs, in Android Studio (recommended) it's possible.